# radio button in wizard

Tags: extjs, extjs3, radio-group

I'm working with extjs 3. while I open first time a wiz card then all radio group are showing properly. but when I close the wiz card and open again that then all radio group are not showing.

```
xtype: 'radiogroup',
id: 'industry_select_type',
fieldLabel: 'Select By',
columns: 1,
items: [{
    boxLabel: 'None',
    name: 'industry_select_type',
    inputValue: '1', // do not set this field to 0, otherwise the radiogroup will not work properly.
    checked: true,
    listeners: {
        check: function (cb, checked) {
            toggleCheck(Ext.getCmp('indTree').root, false);
        }
    }
}, {
    boxLabel: 'All Industries',
    name: 'industry_select_type',
    inputValue: '2',
    listeners: {
        check: function (cb, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                Ext.getCmp('indTree').hide();
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    boxLabel: 'Specific Industries',
    name: 'industry_select_type',
    inputValue: '3',
    listeners: {
        check: function (cb, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                Ext.getCmp('indTree').show();
            } else {
                Ext.getCmp('indTree').hide();
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: ExtJs doesn't have a wizard class. And how are you creating and closing your "wizard"? You are using an `id` so if you create your component multiple times the `DOM` gets confused.

Comment: I agree with @A1rPun - please create example on jsfidle or show full used code here.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ID of your Radiogroup object.